# Realm Data for all users without authorizing

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Is it possible to create some parts of data available for users like list of shop products without authorizing but only authorized users can change informations about products or create new ones?

I assume that if I won't use `/~/` in path it will be data accessible for everyone, but can users change this data?

Comment: What users? Where users? How are you sharing Realms between users? What's the usecase? What is going on?

Comment: See Realm Mobile Platform.

Comment: oh, you're using Sync Realms. Okay, that's important

Comment: Permission Realm support is being added to bindings and also https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#access-control and https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#authorization